# Qual a diferença entre setAttibute, getAttribute e hasAttribute?

Tags: javascript

`hasAttribute` é a evolução do `getAttribute` e `setAttibute`? estou aprendendo JavaScript mas estou em duvida sobre o que cada um faz, o `getAttribute` eu sei que pega um atributo,o `seAttribute` eu sei que seta um atributo e o `hasAttribute` eu não entendi bem o que ele faz...

Comment: Os termos em inglês às vezes nos dá dicas do que as coisas fazem: `has` = possui, `get` = obtém, `set` = define ou coloca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, são coisas diferentes:

- [`hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) retorna um boolean, informando se um atributo existe no elemento;
- [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/getAttribute) retorna o valor de um atributo;
- [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/getAttribute) atribui o valor a um atributo;

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("elemento"); 


// retorna false, atributo xxx não foi definido
console.log(e.hasAttribute("xxx"));
// aqui define o atributo xxx
e.setAttribute("xxx","qualquer coisa");
// agora retorna true porque xxx foi definido
console.log(e.hasAttribute("xxx"));
// retorna o valor de xxx
console.log(e.getAttribute("xxx"));
// retorna true porque o atributo mensagem foi definido no elemento
console.log(e.hasAttribute("mensagem"));
// retorna o valor de mensagem
console.log(e.getAttribute("mensagem"));
```

```html
<span id="elemento" mensagem="olá">Um elemento span</span>
```

Comment: Excelente, obrigado amigo!